# Этимология слова "знаменитый"

Tags: этимология

Задумалась над словом "знаменитый". Интересно, от какого слова оно может происходить? Сразу напрашивается версия - от слова "знание". То есть знаменитый - тот, кого знают практически все. Но, с другой стороны, на него похоже слово "знамя", и тогда приходит другой вариант: изначально это тот, кто носил знамя (а его в военном строю всегда видно, и он всегда впереди).
Интересно было бы узнать, какая версия правильная, и если никакая, то от какого слова на самом деле происходит слово "знаменитый" (пардон за тавтологию).

Answer (score 5):

"Знаменитый" родственно и "знанию", и "знамени", хотя образовано от слова "знамя", но не в том значении.

Знаменитый = знамя (в первоначальном значении "знак", "знак отличия", "отметина") + суфф. -ИТ-со знач большой степени признака.В диалектах до сих пор употребляют слово "знамя" в значении "примета, клеймо", "зарубка". Знаменитый - пользующийся известностью, отличием от других, на него указали (знак = указание), отличили.

Ср. знамение-указание, знак, явление. От него - знаменовать, предзнаменовать - предзнаменование.

Мат. знак знаменатель - указатель, на сколько частей разделена единица.

В др.-р. от глагола знать образ. сущ. знакъ - черта, рубец, пометка, отличие. От него - значити - делать метки, ставить знак, потом глагол переосмыслился в "означать" - иметь содержание, смысл (18 век). От него - значение.

Answer (score 3):

Хронология событий такова.

1) ЗНАТЬ - и.-е основа gen/gno - знать, понимать, о.-с. основа znati.
Др.-рус. с 11 века "знати" - знать, признавать, соблюдать.

Сравнить: know (англ),  kennen (нем.) - знать.

2) ЗНАК - от глагола "знати" - 11 век, то, что позволяет узнать, отличие.

3) ЗНАМЯ - от "знати", с 14 века - знак отличия, печать, помета, с 16 века - воинское знамя.

4) ЗНАМЕНИТЫЙ - от "знамя" в значении знак отличия - отмеченный, выделенный, потом - прославленный. Образовалось раньше, чем "воинское знамя".

Answer (score 1):

Во все времена (как в древности, так и сейчас) людей за какие-либо заслуги отмечали знаками: лавровый венок, орден, звание и т.д.  Делалось это прилюдно, дабы человек становился примером, или антипримером (преступников так же прилюдно обозначали, например клеймили). Таким образом, человек не просто становился носителем знаков отличия, но приобретал известность, становясь **знаменитостью**.  Слово «знамя» - это усиленная, возвышенная форма «знака».  Знак отличия не одного человека, а полка становится **знаменем**, а важный знак судьбы – **знамением**. Так же следует проанализировать и сам «знак». Нас окружает множество форм, некоторые из которых выделяются и наделяются особыми свойствами. Знак – это наиболее ёмкое в информационном и эмоциональном смысле явление. Умение понимать эти явления, проникать в их суть, а так же обозначать, т.е. самому наделять их особыми свойствами, делает человека знатоком, но не знаменитостью. На Руси определённый класс людей называли «знатью». Эти люди так же имели знаки отличия, например - родовые гербы, не все из них были знаменитостями, так как подобные знаки передавались просто по наследству,  и людьми знания – знатоками были так же не все. Вывод могу сделать следующий: **знаменитый** происходит от слова знак, а по поводу самого знака уже ответили другие участники.